# Are road bike shifter hoods compatible across models?

Tags: shimano, parts, replacement

I've been using Shimano Sora Shifters since about 2012 .. probably one generation before the current
(https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/sora-3500/ST-3500.html)

The rubber covers are now corroded and slimy so I want to change them, but I am not sure if they are available for an old model. I’m wondering if I use a cover for a different model, how likely will it be compatible?

Anyone familiar with this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'd be surprised if they're compatible: it's hard to market the latest generation of shifters unless it has new! IMPROVED!! ERGONOMIKZ!!1!, i.e., is a different shape. I'd check for the availability of parts for the old model, rather than just assuming that you can't get htem.

Comment: No, but many are available as non-original branded items. You'll have to trawl auction sites.

Comment: I think there's possibly another separate question here  - how to rejuvenate gummy hoods ?

Comment: If hoods get grubby cleaning them with warm dish-washing water and a saucepan brush often works wonders.

Answer (score 4):

In general, shifter hoods are not compatible between models. Campagnolo has had three different designs since the 90s and Shimano has had many more. If you know the exact model and year of your levers, you should be able to find both original and third party replacement parts online. Competent online stores should have a selection of hoods and list for compatible levers for each.

Comment: And the local bike shop  can probably order stuff even if you can't  find it yourself.

Comment: If they know the thing you are looking for exists and their suppliers have it. Products like this are great examples of so-called long tail.